# Calling a function with a promise into a foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting this error:

```
"lambdaCallbackWith": [
      "TypeError: #<Promise> is not a function",
      "at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)",
```

When i ran the code below:

```
   var resizeVolume =  function* (event, context) {          

        var co = require('co');
        volumes.forEach(co(function *(volume) {

         yield eC2.setNewVolume(volume.VolumeId, volumeSize);                        
        })); 
    }
```

The error occurred in foreach, i added the CO but no success.

The code without CO show an error saying the yield is a reserved word.

Comment: Why are you still using `co`? Upgrade your environment to a version that supports `async`/`await`.

Comment: That said, [don't do any promise stuff in `forEach` callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572)

Comment: Because is a legacy project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yield` can only be used in a generator function. That's why

```
volumes.forEach(() => {
    yield ...
})
```

Won't work.

You will need a library to use a generator in a `forEach` loop such as [co-foreach](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-foreach).

If you don't want to you can use a regular `for` loop like this:

```
const co = require('co');

var resizeVolume =  function* (event, context) {          
    co.wrap(function *() {
        for (let i = 0 ; i < volumes.lenght ; i++) {
            const volume = volumes[i];
            yield eC2.setNewVolume(volume.VolumeId, volumeSize);
        }                       
    }); 
}
```